# How to add and remove a class if another element is clicked in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to toggle a class of body when a button is clicked by using the AngularJS **`ngClass`** directive.

I have added a variable `ng-model="add"` to the button:

```
<md-button aria-label="Add" class="md-icon-button" ng-model="wrong">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="other:add" md-menu-align-target></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Then I added to the body the classes to toggle:

```
<body class="ctr-hidden" ng-class="{'ctr-show': add, 'ctr-hidden': add}">
```

but it does not work, because it adds both the class `'ctr-show'` and class `'ctr-hidden'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('ToggleClassCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.classIsSet = false;
  
        $scope.toggleClass = function() {
            $rootScope.classIsSet = !$rootScope.classIsSet;
        };
    });
```

```css
.result-block.ctr-show {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.result-block.ctr-hidden {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.result-block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="result-block" ng-class="{'ctr-show': classIsSet, 'ctr-hidden': !classIsSet}">
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ToggleClassCtrl">
        <button ng-click="toggleClass()">Toggle the class</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully follow your question but surely you want something like

```
<body ng-class="{'ctr-show': add, 'ctr-hidden': !add}">
```

Comment: It does not look like an answer